# Asymptotic growth of recurrence relation $x_n=\min\limits_{n_1+n_2=n}(a(x_{n_1}+x_{n_2})+2n_1n_2)$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrences

Suppose $a>0$ . Define
$$x_n=\min_{n_1+n_2=n}(a(x_{n_1}+x_{n_2})+2n_1n_2) \text{ with } x_1=0.$$ 
Can we find $r>0$ such that there exists two positive constant $c_1,c_2$ such that 
$$c_1<\frac{x_n}{n^r}<c_2$$ for sufficiently large $n$? If such $r$ exists, what is the value of $r$?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you tell us something about the context?

Comment: Did you tried to check it numerically? It will be much easier to prove such statement by induction than to come up with one.

Comment: I think that you can prove by induction that for any positive $\epsilon$ there exist $C_1,C_2$ s.t. $C_1 n^{log_2 a-\epsilon}<x_n<C_2 n^{max(log_2 a,2)+\epsilon}$, for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: This is begging for some numerical experimentation (for several $a$) and educated hypothesis-making. Finding the exponent of best fit to a polynomial-ish growing sequence is an easy computational task.

Comment: I assume that both $n_1$ and $n_2$ are supposed to be strictly less than $n$. Then $x_1$ is not defined.

Comment: Simulations seem to confirm that for $a<1$, the value of $r$ is 1, whereas as for $a=1$, the value of $r$ is 2. For $a>1$, the value of $r$ appears to depend on $a$; moreover, in a log-log plot the graph of $x_n$ does not appear to be linear but rather piecewise concave.

Comment: For large $a$  I think $$x_n\ge f(n):=\frac{n^{1+\log_2 a}-n^2}{a-2},$$  because $f$ verifies the analogous relation with continuous parameter minimization for $x\ge2$: $$f(x)=\min_{1\le t \le x-1}\{a\big(f(t)+f(x-t)\big)+2t(x-t)\}=2a f(x/2)+x^2/2,$$  by convexity and symmetry of the  expression to minimize. I think $a\ge3$ is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Some back-of-the-frontal-lobe calculations:

One gets $x_2=2$ and $x_3=2a+4$, given the limited number of sums.  For $x_4$, we have a choice of
$4a+8$ or $2a^2 +4a +6$, and for $x_5$ either $2a^2 +6a +12$ or $2a^3 +4a^2 +6a + 8$ or $4a^2 +8a +8$.

If $a \lt 1/2n$  then $x_i \lt 2i$ for $i$ up to $n$ and perhaps further.  If $a=0$, then $x_n =2(n-1)$, so if there is an $r$, it must be $r \geq 1$.  If $a \leq 1$, it should not be hard to show $x_n=O(n^2)$.  I imagine, but have not proved, that for $a>1$ $x_n$ is $O(a^{n/2})$.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.10.03

Comment: actually  for $a=1$  $x_n=n(n-1)$, so it is true what you say for $a\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on numerical experiments I found that for $0<a<1$ the minimum is always at $n_{1}=1$ and $n_{2}=n-1$. This conjecture can be proven by induction in $n$ for an $a=1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ and small. (I guess, if it is proven for $a$ near 1, i.e. to $O(\epsilon)$, it is true for all smaller $a$, because all coefficients of the resulting polynomial in $a$ are positive.) The solution then can be given in closed form:
$$
x_{n}=2\frac{n - 1 - n a + a^n}{(1-a)^{2}}.
$$
(It is a polynomial since the numerator has a double zero at $a=1$.) Thus $r=1$ for $0<a<1$ is correct.

Same as Pietro in his comment I found for $a>1$ (again by experiments using Mathematica) that
$$
x_{2^{m}}=2^{m} \frac{2^{m}-a^{m}}{2-a}
$$
which means (for $n=2^m$)
$$
x_{n}=\frac{n}{a-2}\left(a^{\ln n/\ln 2}-n\right)
$$
The latter is $O(n^{2})$ for $1<a<2$. For $a>2$ it has the more complicated asymptotics, $O(n a^{\ln n/\ln 2})$ (Edit: or, what is the same, $O(n^{1+\ln a/ \ln 2})$).

I could not prove formally the implicit assumption, that for $a>1$ the minimum in the recursion formula is at $n_{1}=n_{2}=n/2$ for $n$ even; and, for $n$ odd, $n_{1}=(n-1)/2$ and $n_{2}=(n+2)/2$. But I am pretty sure that I am right based on the results Mathematica gave me.